# PostgreSQL: FOREIGN KEY/ON DELETE CASCADE/TRIGGER

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have 3 tables:

Detail

Detail_Archive

Transaction_Results

Transaction_Results is a new table that I did not build and has a constraint that I could probably remove altogether, but I would believe that it might break some functions that I assume it was built for.

```
ALTER TABLE Transaction_Results
ADD Constraint Transaction_Results_Detail_DetailID_fkey FOREIGN KEY (DetailID)
REFERENCES Details (DetailID) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Now in the past I simply copied and deleted records out of Detail and into Detail_Archive

What would be the most common way(s) to keep the constraint?
My idea would be: maybe making it null-able and setting the values I remove to null, perhaps moving them to an additional column referencing the archive version of the table and making that one null-able as well. In my code where I needed this I will have to deal with this problem but that isn't so bad for me.

Comment: It's a FOREIGN KEY, it ensures that for each value of DetailID in this table, there is a record in Details table with the same value of DetailID. [wiki FK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Comment: Yes... That's my problem....

Comment: Well, the obvious (and probably wrong) answer would be to stop deleting rows from "Detail" or "Details". That seems to be what "Transaction_Results" was designed to do. The simplest fixes would be to either drop the constraint or make it `on delete cascade`. You need to know how rows end up in "Transaction_Results" or how to find the designer to know which is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took the brute force approach.

```
ALTER TABLE Transaction_Results DROP CONSTRAINT Transaction_Results_Detail_DetailID_fkey ;
ALTER TABLE Transaction_Results ALTER COLUMN DetailID DROP NOT NULL;

 ALTER TABLE Transaction_Results ADD COLUMN DetailID_Archive integer NULL;

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_Detail_delete() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $Transaction_Results_trigger$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Update a row in Transaction_Results to reflect the delete performed on Detail,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            UPDATE  Transaction_Results SET DetailID = NULL, DetailID_Archive =  OLD.DetailID where DetailID = OLD.DetailID ;
            RETURN OLD;

        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$Transaction_Results_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER Transaction_Results_trigger
AFTER  DELETE ON [Detail]
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_Detail_delete();​
```